# Run page (html with ajax) in background of Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ajax

I know there are many other ways to do what I want but I am just with free time and try to learn something. I have an HTML page that uses a very simple JS code (below) to get GPS data from the smartphone and after that I send it to my webserver using ajax.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(save_location,report_error,{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:60,maximumAge:0});
```

If I open my HTML page on my Chrome browser inside my smartphone everyting works fine, I mean: my webserver receives the data from the browser and saves it to the database. But after sometime my phone gets locked (after 20 secs) or Chrome simply stops rendering the page even if I disable the lock of my phone.

So I ask you this: is there any app that I can install on my phone and it keeps running a custom URL (or HTML PAGE) in the background?

EDIT: the HTML page gets the GPS coords and sends it to a server using AJAX at every 60 seconds, so I need to keep this page running in the background in order to get GPS data at every 60 seconds.

Comment: So the request is being made/received/processed but the page hangs?

Comment: Yes, the page a really simple HTML reads the GPS coords and sends it to a webserver using simple AJAX. The page keeps doing that infinitly, after 60 seconds it does the same thing and repeats it on and on

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve this, possibly by utilizing your own WebView and client. I haven't ever tried infinitely running mobile sites, but I don't think the OS is going to be happy about this scenario.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using a webview but chrome does not allow it to run in background :(

Comment: You could always just get your location from your phone and push it to a web service that would save it on the backend instead of utilizing the site to do the geolocation... just an option.

Comment: @zgc7009 your option is good but it would be much more easier to me to stick with plain JS. I think it will be easier to me create and app with webview